# Difference Between Array and Collections

Tags: arrays, collections, terminology

I read somewhere that array's are underlying data structures while collection are standard data structure can somebody explain this terminology I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rapidprogramming.com/questions-answers/java-arrays-and-collections-differences-arrays-vs-collections-1604

this might help. Apart from this you can find other useful links also if you search on google.